# Loop and multiply 3 different numpy arrays by random percents which add up to 100%

Tags: numpy, for-loop, math, random, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have these three arrays.

```
array1 = np.array([4,5,6])
array2 = np.array([3,2,1])
array3 = np.array([2,3,5])
```

I want to create a loop that multiplies each array by a random percent, but the three percents must add up to 100%. For example on the first loop it may do the following

```
array1 * 30%
array2 * 20%
array3 * 50%
```

And on the second loop it does a different random percent for each array

```
array1 * 15%
array2 * 90%
array3 * 5%
```

If anyone has any ideas how to make this loop possible please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ask for a loop:

```
for _ in range(10):
    weights = np.random.rand(3)
    weights = weights/weights.sum()

    # multiply
    array1 * weights[0]
    ....
```

Comment: Legend. Thanks Quang!